# Fetch matrix field attributes in controller

Tags: matrix, controller

In my controller I fetched the `Entry`

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria('Entry');
$criteria->section = 'offlineEvents';
$event = $criteria->first();
```

The Entry has a matrix field with handler called `eventDetails`

How can I access this matrix field values? I want to do it like I'd do it in template:

```
{% for items in entry.eventDetails %}
    {% if items.getType() == 'heading' %}  
     ....
```

but I cant do

```
foreach ($event->eventDetails as $details) { ... }
```

it's giving me empty array.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks right. I'd double check for spelling mistakes and check if there's a entry model returned from your `$event = $criteria->first();` by outputting its ID with `return $event->id`.

Comment: yes, there is the id that I can output. Also I can output the `$event->title`. Very weird behaviour detected: In my code above I changed `$criteria->section = 'offlineEvents';` to `$criteria->section = 'products';` The products have their own matrix field `productDetailBody`. And now I can do `foreach ($event->productDetailBody as $details) { ... }` This in fact works. I double checked the Events entry created correctly, I even deleted it and created one from scratch, trying spelling different handlers. Also new events entries give 404 on frontend. any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe your criteria model isnt explicit enough and you're getting an entry back with an empty matrix field. Try to be more restricive, by adding an `$criteria->entryType = 'offlineEvents';` or for testing purposes an `$criteria->id = 24;` filter.

Comment: nope, doesn't work either. I think I'm missing something. I just created simples `Test` section, type of `Channel`, added a test entry into it, named test 1, and I navigate on frontend to /test/test-1 and it's 404. Also there is no preview button on admin while editing the entry. In the Section edit screen there is the checkbox 'each entry has its own url'... I recentlry upgraded craft to latest version, I thing this is somehow related..

Comment: This /test/test-1 routing issue is unrelated to getting an element model via a method like `craft()->elements->getCriteria('Entry');`.

Comment: Agreed, it's not related. Do you have something in mind as to 404 issue?